# how to remove both first and last line of csv file using sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I can remove the first line of csv file's starting with `myfile` and merge them using:

```
sed 1d myfile*.csv > myfile_merged.csv
```

I'd like to also remove the last line of the csv files.

I've tried:

```
sed 1d -i '$d' myfile*.csv > myfile_merged.csv
```

But get the error:

```
sed: can't read $d: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is this command:

```
sed 1d -i '$d' myfile*.csv > myfile_merged.csv
```

You need not have an argument after `-i` (**inline replacement**) in `sed` otherwise it is treated as a `SUFFIX` to create a backup for inline replacement.

What you need is this `gnu sed` command:

```
sed -i '1d;$d' myfile*.csv
```

This will remove 1st and last line in each of the matched file and save it in place.

Comment: FYI, this can be achieved using non-GNU sed as well. For BSD sed, the only difference is that you'd provide a null string for the optarg, like: `sed -i '' '1d;$d' *.csv`. Though I gather this isn't what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes I know about that because I work on OSX. Though `-i ''` will give error for `gnu sed` so I prefer a proper suffix i.e. `sed -i.bak '1d;$d' *.csv` which works for both versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably trying to do is:

```
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' myfile*.csv > merged.csv
```

But this won't work, because it tells sed to remove the first and last line of ALL files, rather than EACH file.  In other words, you'll strip the first line of the first file, and the last line of the last file ... and that's it.

To process each file individually, you probably need to process each file .. individually.  :)

```
for f in myfile*.csv
    sed -e '1d;$d' "$f"
done > merged.csv
```

Note that while this will run in bash, it's also POSIX compatible (both the shell and sed parts). And it does not care whether your input is CSV or any other format, as long as it can be parsed line by line using sed.

Comment: not sure if some versions don't have it, but you can use `-s` option to have separate addressing for each input file

Comment: @Sundeep, yes, the `-s` option is a GNUism. I purposely keep things more portable, especially when (as is the case here) we don't know the OP's operating system.